# Grant object permissions Azure SQL Server incorrect syntax

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-grant

I am trying to integrate Azure SQL Server with Zapier. To do so I need to set permissions for the Zapier IP address.

When I run the following query

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON db_name.test TO "zapier"@"54.86.9.50" IDENTIFIED BY "Password";
```

I get the following error

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'zapier'

I have already tried `[username]@[ip address]` and that did not work either.

Could someone help me resolve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hi as it saying syntax error try giving single quotes   'zapier'

```
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON db_name.test TO 'zapier'@'54.86.9.50' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
```